# Book about actress forced to disguise alien murderer

Tags: story-identification

I read this book once when I was in middle school. A girl solves a murder or a mystery on a spaceship. It was a thin paperback books.

All I can remember is that there was an alien, and there was a movie star or actress or famous makeup artist on the ship traveling with another woman. By the end of the book the murderer was the woman the actress was traveling with who forced her to use her makeup skills to disguise her, and she was really some kind of alien.

Comment: When were you in middle school? Last month? Year? In 1990s?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is [Alien Secrets](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0788706861), by Annette Kurtis Clause.  It is indeed a thin paperback, and published in 1997.

There was an alien, who the main character (Puck) befriends, and a famous actress who was traveling with another woman - who ended up being a different alien, hiding under the actress's makeup skills, not only murderous but trying to frame the original alien for the deaths and the theft of smuggled artifacts.

There was also a red herring of a character who is originally the one the main character suspects, someone else smuggling artifacts with those trying to catch them (both the law and other smugglers like the murderous alien), and ghosts following a stolen artifact, and a number of other interesting things.

Comment: omg thank you so much i was looking for this book forever

Comment: @JamesLindsey - glad I could help :)